# XML Tags Being Removed from Data in PHP Page Retrieve from AWS DynamoDB

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Sketched out a PHP page to pull data from a DynamoDB table. The page pulls a field with XML data, `submissionMessageSent`, and displays it twice.

- **First Occurrence:** Looks like the data with the XML tags missing.
- **Second Occurrence:** Looks like the data with the XML tags in place.

Between the two occurrences the variable isn't updated by code in the page. The data is stored w/tags in Dynamo as a big old string.

[image]

Why are the XML tags stripped out in one case but not the other?

[image: Rendered Page]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Spyglass</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="get">
            Submission Identifier: <input name="submission_id" type="submission_identifier" size="45" value="<?php $submissionId ?>"/>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <?php
            date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

            $configs = include('./config.php');

            require './vendor/autoload.php';

            use Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException;
            use Aws\DynamoDb\Marshaler;

            if ( isset($_GET["submission_id"]) && $_GET["submission_id"] != "" ) {
                $aws_credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials(
                    $configs['aws_account_key'],
                    $configs['aws_account_secret']
                );

                $sdk = new Aws\Sdk([
                    'region'  => $configs['aws_region_identifier'],
                    'version' => "2012-08-10",
                    'credentials' => $aws_credentials
                ]);

                $dynamodb = $sdk->createDynamoDb();
                $marshaler = new Marshaler();

                $ddb_query_predicate = '{":id": "' . $_GET["submission_id"] . '"}';
                $eav = $marshaler->marshalJson($ddb_query_predicate);

                $params = [
                    'TableName' => "Orders",
                    'KeyConditionExpression' => '#submissionId = :id',
                    'ExpressionAttributeNames'=> ["#submissionId" => "submissionId"],
                    'ExpressionAttributeValues' => $eav
                ];

                try {
                    $submissionQueryResponse = $dynamodb->query($params);

                    $submission = $submissionQueryResponse['Items'][0];
                    $submissionObject = $marshaler->unmarshalItem($submission, true);

                    // Extract the message sent to the ERP system by the preprocessor
                    $submissionMessageSent = $submissionObject->submissionMessageSent;
echo "<p><b>1:</b> $submissionMessageSent</p>";

                    echo <<<EOT
<textarea id="sent" wrap="off" placeholder="Sent" rows="20" cols="75">$submissionMessageSent</textarea>
EOT;

                } catch (DynamoDbException $e) {
                    echo "Unable to query:\n";
                    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**NOTE**: Complete disclosure. I had to pull out portions of the page's code to not disclose sensitive information. Don't crucify me if I missed a tag some place in the purge. You get the gist of my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML is rendered as HTML, they are ignored by the webbrowser. It possible to see them within the textarea as this will escape the tag's characters.

The tags will be there when viewing the raw html output.

Comment: To those that stumble upon this, @thisiisboris is spot on. If I view the source, I see the tags. Thanks Boris!